# Android Fragment Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment

### i have below error when create simple fragment example.

```
09-05 07:57:28.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1138): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.fragment_one.f_one: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fragments_one/com.example.fragments_one.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class fragment
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class fragment
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at com.example.fragments_one.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     ... 11 more
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.fragment_one.f_one: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:395)
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:363)
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:264)
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     ... 21 more
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.fragment_one.f_one
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:385)
09-05 08:57:03.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1477):     ... 24 more
```

---

Main Activity

```
package com.example.fragments_one;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/f_one"
        android:name="com.example.fragment_one.f_one"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/f_two"
        android:name="com.example.fragment_one.f_two"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment Layouts

1.f_one.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#00FF00"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is fragment #1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

f_two.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFE00"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is fragment #2"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

my fragment Class

```
package com.example.fragments_one;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class f_one extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ---Inflate the layout for this fragment---
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.f_one, container, false);
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.example.fragments_one;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class f_two extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ---Inflate the layout for this fragment---
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.f_two, container, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to mention **class** in fragment :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/f_one"
    android:name="com.example.fragment_one.f_one"
    class="com.example.fragment_one.f_one"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/f_two"
    android:name="com.example.fragment_one.f_two"
    class="com.example.fragment_one.f_two"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Pardon @Dhaval....I didn't get you.